Again on Django template inheritance
The difficulty I have is precisely described in
Django Accessing Parent Data in templates from child data
but the answer given there, accepted by the OP, is given in the “recipe” spirit,
as are an incredible number of others I found, concerning the same issue.
Even the django official documentation, having to document an enormously vast field,
suffers from this disease.
So, since I would like not the fish but the fishing rod, please let me restate the question in my terms:
I have a father template and children templates, the latter all filling one block defined
in the father template, one at a time.
The father template is shown by calling a father-view in father.py, with a father-context,
and the view-template relation for the father is given by a line in some urls.py file.
This fills the upper part of the browser screen with some type of “summary data”.
When this is done, it is time to fill up the lower part, with different types of detail information, one at a time of course. I do this with different children views, using in the father-template idioms like
{% url ‘djangoapp:details1’ param1_a %} 

or
{% url ‘djangoapp:details2’ param2_a param2_b param2_c %}

and so on.
These “children views” all generate different “children contexts”, each one of which
is sent to its own “child template”, “{% extend %}”-ing the “father template” above.
This works, in the sense that it fills the lower part of my page, but the upper page at this point is full of blank spaces.
As I understand it, this is because the children-contexts do not contain
any of the variables I use in the upper part of my page. So I ask:

Is my interpretation correct? and,
Am I to fix this by passing in the “url” lines above each and all of the parameters
received from the father template, totally unneeded by the children views,
just for having the children views include them in their children contexts
for final transmission to the children templates?

This is, in essence, what the OP was answered in the question in the link above.
But they are more than 2 or 3, and would clutter everything: the “url” lines above,
the definition of the children views, and also the description lines in the urls.py file.
Since my case seems common enough, I find strange that the django system
of “template inheritance” was not completed by “context inheritance” of some kind.
Thank you for answers, or suggestions.

I think the easiest way would be to provide the "father" context variable with all things in the template, .e.g.
...
{% block father %}
...
{# use father.attribute to render #}
...
{% if child %}
  {% block child %}
    {# use child.attribute to render #}
    ...
  {% endblock child %}
...
{% endblock father %}

Now you can use the same template for both
def father_view(request, ...):
    ...
    father = ...
    return render(request, template, context={'father': father} 


def child_view(request, ...):
    ...
    child = ...
    father = child.father  # for example
    return render(request, template, context={'father': father, 'child': child})

Of course, you could use template inheritance, but in this case I think it isn't needed. (In this case, the father template would have an empty child block which would be extended by the child template.
Anyhow you need to:

access the father using the same variables in both father and child template sections
show child content only if it's provided.

The {{father.attribute}} and {{child.attribute}} syntax allows you to easily distinguish where the content comes from. If you add new attributes to models, you won't have to change the view code.
